# Youtube API v3 for ASP.NET Working Example

Tags: asp.net, youtube.net-api

I am looking at the documentation for hours now. May be someone here can help me out.

I am planning to add our project a functionality which will provide users to upload their videos to YouTube directly without the need to logon to Youtube.com and upload it there. I tried creating a sample project using the codes on

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet

But couldn't succeed. Then began googling for an example (working) but all the search results are for older versions of api, or copies of the codes in the link below.

In nuget, there is a package: [Google.GData.YouTube](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.GData.YouTube/2.2.0)

So, I created a project which has that package installed. What to do next?
(.net sample on youtube api documentation not working with that package - Is that nuget package for v2 or smth?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use "YouTube Direct Lite"
you can read about it on the following link:
https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/

Also you can see the following video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ZE89VsBq3o

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Actually this is the answer to my question and since this "YouTube Direct Lite" is a huge project, adding links here is enough just to guide me. +1 for the youtube video link about the subject.

Answer (score 0):

NuGet package Google.GData.YouTube uses this API http://gdata.youtube.com/ which refers itself as v2.0.

There is also NuGet [Google.Apis.YouTube.v3 Client Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.YouTube.v3) which uses YT v3 API.

The example you are referring to is using this Client Library.